# How to build with IOS 16.0 on recently installed XCode 14.1

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I recently uploaded my react native ios app to Testflight but I got a warning email stating:

```
This app was built with the iOS 15.5 SDK. Starting April 25, 2023, all iOS and iPadOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 16.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 14.1 or later.
```

I was using XCode 13.1 so I decided to download XCode Version 14.1 (14B47b), when I open the huge list of simulators I only find my old XCode 13 simulators (IOS 15.0), I decided to check Preferences -> Platforms and it says IOS 16.0 is built-in...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjHDo.png

My simulators list:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6Egi.png

So how can I BUILD and ARCHIVE my project with IOS 16.0 when I can't specifically select IOS 16.0?

Will it use 16.0 by default now that I'm using 14.1 instead?

Comment: If you're updating Xcode update to the latest version. You are already 2 versions behind with 14.1. The latest is 14.3.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using https://www.xcodes.app/ to manage the different versions of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Updating your xcode must solve the issue! And before building your archive in simulators select Any Ios Device.

I am using xcode 14.2 with no issue.

Starting April 25, 2023, iOS, iPadOS, and watchOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 14.1 or later. **The latest version of Xcode 14, which includes the latest SDKs for iOS 16, iPadOS 16, and watchOS 9**

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=jd9wcyov